# Learn Ruby The Hard Way Chapter 9 Triple Quotes

Tags: ruby, string-literals

Zed Shaw's Learn Ruby the Hard Way chapter 9 uses triple double quotes:

```
puts """
There's something going on here.
With the three double-quotes.
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
"""
```

I tried writing the same thing with single double quotes and it seems to work fine. I don't understand the difference between triple and single double quotes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like he's confusing Ruby and Python.

Comment: Maybe Zed was thinking of triple less than signs (heredocs) http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know why he uses triple double quotes in his book. They're nothing special, and one double quote works just fine.

This is a little known "feature" of ruby - it simply glues adjacent strings together.

```
s = "hello " "world" # equivalent to "hello " + "world"
s # => "hello world"
```

So your example is equivalent to

```
puts "" + "
There's something going on here.
With the three double-quotes.
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
" + ""
```

More string tricks: http://pivotallabs.com/stupid-ruby-quoting-tricks/

Comment: you included a space in the first string, so the return would be "hello world".

Comment: @aceofbassgreg: ah, sorry! forgot to update evaluation result.

Answer (score 5):

I think you found a mistake in the book - the reason he uses triple quotes may be that Python allows you to write strings over multiple lines only when using triple quotes, so it might have been that he took over the example from "Learning Python the Hard Way" or simply mixed up languages.

In Ruby, you can include new lines even in single quotes.

Let him know about that, I'm sure he'll appreciate it.

Comment: What is the mistake? There's nothing wrong with the code (other than it having some unnecessary quotes, which I expect was the point he was making).

Comment: @CarySwoveland the text in the triple quotes reads: `"""There's something going on here.
With the three double-quotes.
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6."""` which implies that in Ruby triple quotes are needed to be able to write multiline strings. This is true for Python, but not for Ruby

Comment: Ha! I had paid no attention to what the quoted words were saying!

Comment: The text in the triple quotes reads differently than what you present here, @BeatRichartz, in that it misses the newline at the beginning of the string.  It is in fact what is different between using a quote and a HereDoc, in that if you try to use them in the same way, you may end up missing that the string starts with a new line character. (also you don't present the text ending new line character.)

Comment: @vgoff the point in me writing down the text here was to show what the text reads. I agree that there is confusion about python's triple quote multiline string syntax being a form of heredoc (it is not), but the confusion here is not about it being a heredoc, but about it being ruby syntax mandatory to build multiline strings (it is not, it's python syntax). In fact, I quoted the text in my commentary without *any* of the newlines in it, so it's an absolute inaccurate representation of what's actually in the book, but I think it serves its purpose well transporting the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: No problem.  I took it as a literal quote due to the coding quotes you used, rather than a grammatical quote.  "There's something going on here. With the three double-quotes. We'll be able to type as much as we like. Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6." would have communicated that, unlike the `"""something here"""` signified a literal quote for code, as that was how it was presented.  No problem.